# http.HandleFunc with Static Files

Tags: go

I am building a webpage.  The page should be able to handle the different `http` methods (`GET`, `POST`...).  My page technically works and handles each type of request, but in the case of `GET` requests (serving `index.html` at the root `"/"` path), my page is not displaying properly.  None of the images or css are displaying correctly, presumably because those files cannot be found.

[image: Ugly page]

I have noticed that `http.Handle` provides better results than `http.HandleFunc` when substituted into my `server.go` code below, in that the images and css do display correctly using:

```
http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))
```

The following is my web server with images and css not being displayed correctly.  In general, my intent is to use static files for everything, including html (ex. `index.html`) and to implement some solution using nothing but standard go.

**server.go code**

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Add("Content Type", "text/html")
  switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
      http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/index.html")
    case "POST":
      fmt.Pprintf(w, "POST!")
    case "PUT":
      fmt.Pprintf(w, "PUT!")
    case "DELETE":
      fmt.Pprintf(w, "DELETE!")
    default:
      fmt.Pprintf(w, "Default!")
  }
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hard-coded your server to always return `index.html` for any GET request, no matter what is being requested. So if your `index.html` includes a reference to `style.css`, the browser is going to make a second request for `style.css` and you'll return `index.html` again.

I assume what you're trying to do is have all `GET` requests return static files, while other verbs will do something else. You just need to pass those along to the file server:

```
root := "static"
...
case "GET":
    if r.URL.Path == "" || r.URL.Path == "/" {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, path.Join(root, "index.html"))
    } else {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, path.Join(root, r.URL.Path))
    }
```

Note that by the time your handler is called, all ".." references in the URL have been removed, attackers can't use this to escape your static tree. But `ServeFile()` will return directory listings, so you'll need to check for that if that's a problem.

Comment: Regarding your evaluation of my original code and my intentions: yes, you are spot on, so thank you for that.  Regarding the code you posted, I got some weird results.  Once I imported `path`, (required for `path.Join`), I was able to compile and run successfully.  Unfortunately, the only improvement I got was in being able to view images.  The css is still broken.  Also, interestingly, I can navigate to `/image.png` and `/style.css` and view those resources.  However, neither are rendered properly in a browser.  In the case of `/image.png`, I just see encrypted characters/text.

Comment: In addition to your changes, removing `w.Header().Add("Content Type", "text/html")` fixed the rendering problem for the image and css files.